# Rename C:\Users\Valued Customer

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I just got a new laptop running Windows Vista, and my username started out as "Valued Customer." That's pretty annoying, so I changed it with the Control Panel settings. But my home directory is still C:\Users\Valued Customer. Is there a safe way to change this? Or should I just create a new user and wipe out the "Valued Customer" one?

Comment: I like the idea that Microsoft values customers...

(this should be on ServerFault)

Comment: That was more likely the laptop vendor creating that.  Not Micro$

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this [tutorial on changing the profile folder location](http://joshmouch.wordpress.com/2007/04/07/change-user-profile-folder-location-in-vista/) will help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click "Start", type "Windows Easy Transfer" (without quotation marks) in the "Start Search" field, and press "Enter".
2. When "Windows Easy Transfer" is launched, click "Next", choose "Start a new transfer", choose "My old computer", choose "Use a CD, DVD, or other
   removable media", and choose "External hard disk or to a network location".
3. Type "D:\user-account.mig" (without quotation marks), and click "Next".

Note: Now, we may need to save the current user account to a certain folder, and please specify a folder and a name for it.

4. Click "Advanced options", make sure that the specific user account profile is selected and other options are cleared, and click "Next".
5. Thus, the specific user account will be saved to "D:\user-account.mig" (without quotation marks). When the transfer is completed, please click
   "Close".
6. Let's launch "Windows Easy Transfer" again, click "Next", and choose "Continue a transfer in progress".
7. Choose "No, I've copied files and settings to a CD, DVD, or other removable media", choose "On an external hard disk or network location", type
   "D:\user-account.mig" (without quotation marks), and click "Next".
8. When we are prompted to choose a username from the list, please type a new username, click "Next", and click "Transfer".

Note: When we create a new user account, the original password is not transferred, and when we log on with the new user account for the first time,
we will be required to create a password for it.

9. Thus, the old user account will be transferred to the new user account, and the log-on username and the store folder will also be changed
   respectively.
10. When the transfer is completed, please click "Close". When we are prompted to log off, let's click "Yes", and log on with the new user account.